# How to run code after multiprocessing part is finished in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am very new to the multiprocessing of python. Currently, I am trying to use multiprocessing for data generation(10 times) and then do some following work. My current code is like:

```
def data_generation(param1, param2, param3):
    main function
    np.save(....)

for i in np.arrange(10):
   if __name__ == '__main__':
   ratio = np.arange(0.3, 1.4, 0.1)
   pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
   param1 = 1
   param2 = 2
   func = partial(data_generation, param1, param2)
   _ = pool.map(func, param3=ratio)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   ### then I would like to read the generated data and do analysis
   result = np.load(..)
```

My idea is like I would like to do one work 10 times. For each time, I generate the data, do the analysis, store the result, and do it again. For the data generation part, one parameter needs to change from 0.3 to 1.4. That's where I want to use multiprocessing.

The problem is every time when I run the code, it looks like python jumped the data generation part and went to the analysis part directly.

So what is the right logic for this task? I hope the data analysis part is exacuated after the data generation part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pool.starmap` which expects a tuple of tuples that are arguments to your function. Here, to show the steps, I generated the tuples ahead of time and stored them in func_arg_tuple.

Also, there is no need for the intermediate step of saving the results in your data_generation function. Just return the value you want to process and it will be in `results` when the pool's work is completed.

```
import multiprocessing

def data_generation(param1, param2, param3):
    # sample processing function - add your own
    return np.random.normal(param3, param1, param2)

param1 = 1
param2 = 2

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
    func_arg_tuple = tuple((param1, param2, ratio) for ratio in np.arange(0.3, 1.4, 0.1))
    results = pool.starmap(data_generation, func_arg_tuple)

>>>results
[array([-0.89459092,  2.03727378]),
 array([-0.79459092,  2.13727378]),
 array([-0.69459092,  2.23727378]),
 array([0.57145244, 0.75501116]),
 array([ 2.40776746, -0.17882601]),
 array([0.77145244, 0.95501116]),
 array([-0.88291467,  1.3072801 ]),
 array([0.97145244, 1.15501116]),
 array([0.0123457 , 2.25667152]),
 array([2.90776746, 0.32117399]),
 array([3.00776746, 0.42117399])]
```